# HTML using jQuery to send a postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website for a clothing brand but am still getting started with my web dev work. I have an index page with several clothing items on it. When a user hovers over the picture of the item then a hover over effect comes into play and a small "View Item" appears over the item. When the user clicks this "View Item" text it opens a new page with that particular page's info.

The part I am struggling with is how I send the parameter to this item page as I will need some way of knowing what item was clicked. Can I write a jQuery function that will fire when the text is clicked and perform a .post() method to the item.php page passing along the item ID ?

So it would be something like

```
$.(document).ready( function() {

    $("#itemText").click( function() {

        $.post("item.php", parameters);
    });
})
```

Comment: *"Can I write a jQuery function that will fire when the text is clicked and perform a .post() method to the item.php page passing along the item ID ?"* Yes. Try out your code and see how it works out.

Comment: You could also just add a parameter onto the view item link url like `/item.php?id=1`.  Then in item.php you can access it with $_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

POST isn't the proper protocol for that. Use GET instead.

GET is vary easy to use with HTML links; it is what happens every time you click a link on a website. Say the page is "products." If the user clicked on product 1, than the URL for that page could potentially be "products/?id=1" (or products/1 if you are using mod_rewrite). The "id" variable with a value of "1" will be available to the PHP via $_GET['id']. With that variable, you can retrieve the proper information based on the id.

POST is for forms where users are submitting fields of data or images. http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

If you are attempting to build a pure Javascript solution, then that is an entirely different matter. In that situation you would use Hash tags or HTML5 History API to change the URL. When the URL changes, Javascript is notified, and then whatever actions can occur. However, based on the fact that you specifically said "POST" I am assuming you are using a server-side language like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a new page, you should not POST. If you must POST, you should POST then Redirect, although since you are not actually performing an action I recommend just sticking with a GET request. This way the newly opened page can easily be refreshed and shared by the viewer.

The most elegant way is to use rewrite rules or a router on your server so you can communicate which item to display, for example: `http://example.com/item/1/`

However you can also just use a GET parameter: `http://example.com/item/?id=1`

If you need to communicate to Javascript that will be executed on a page you can also use a hash: `http://example.com/item/#1`

There are several options using GET depending on how you display the item information, and what server-side technology you use.